# Calculate variogram of raster data with NAs in R

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, geor

**Summary:** I have a raster dataset which contains NA values, and want to calculate a variogram of it, ignoring the NAs. How can I do this?

I have an image which I have loaded into R using the `readGDAL` function, stored as `im`. To make this reproducible, the result of `dput` on the image is available at https://gist.github.com/2780792. I am trying to display a variogram of this data and am struggling. I'll go through what I've tried so far:

I tried the `gstat` package, but couldn't seem to get a function call that would work. I've gathered that basically what I need is the data values themselves (`im@data$band1`) and the coordinates (`coordinates(im)`). I've tried various commands like:

```
> variogram(locations=coordinates(im), y = im@data$band1)
Error in is.list(object) : 'object' is missing
```

and

```
> variogram(coordinates(im), im@data$band1)
Error in variogram.default(coordinates(im), im@data$band1) : 
  argument object and locations should be lists
```

What am I doing wrong here?

As that didn't seem to work, I tried the `geoR` package, which I called using:

```
> variog(coords=coordinates(im), data=im@data$band1)
variog: computing omnidirectional variogram
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

The error looks like it is to do with the data having NAs in it, so I tried to remove them using `na.omit`, but that leaves all of the NAs in there. That kinda makes sense as a raster file *must* have something in each grid square. Is there a way to remove the NAs somehow, or at least make the `variog` command ignore them?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data object passed to `gstat:variogram` is a spatial object (your data is a`SpatialGridDataFrame`) then you do not need to specify the locations, as these are contained in the data.

However, clearly the `NA` values are causing a problem, so if we force the grid object to be a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, this will remove the `NA` values

`im` contains the data https://gist.github.com/2780792

```
library(gstat)
point_data <- as(im, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')
gstat_variogram <- variogram(band1 ~ 1, data = point_data)
```

To use `geoR`

```
library(geoR)
geor_variogram <- variog(coords = coordinates(point_data), 
                          data = point_data@data$band1)
```

or even more simply (as `geoR` works with objects of class `geodata` and contains the function `as.geodata` to convert from a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` to `geodata` object

```
geor_variogram <- variog(as.geodata(point_data))
```